# Run amd64 (x86_64) and i386 (x86) packages on arm64 (aarch64)?

Tags: package-management, java, minecraft

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B running Ubuntu 20.10 with 4GB RAM, the GPU overclocked to 750MHz with 128MB RAM allocated, and the CPU overclocked to 2.5GHz. Is there any possible way to run amd64 packages on this architecture?

*NOTE:

1. It has been proven possible to run arm64 applications on amd64, it should be possible vice-versa.
2. This is primarily to install a more recent version of Minecraft Java edition, recent enough to include the Sign In with Microsoft button.

Comment: Running another CPUs programs requires an interpreter and loads of memory (interpreters are not as efficient).  On 4GB of RAM you'd at best be able to run programs that will run on a 512MB x86 box, and they'd use all resources and walk rather slowly.  In reality it's not worth it, and thus no-one has written (beyond some tests) the code to allow it (its inefficient & wasting resources on devices that have little to waste).   CISC is better at running RISC programs easily, than the other way around you're asking about (RISC needs more code/overhead due to larger CISC instruction set)

Comment: Like guiverc says, the effort isn’t worth it. Your Pi just doesn’t have the capability. If you really must do this, QEMU is the only option you’ll have and you’ll be disappointed with the results.